# Algorithm to find numbers larger than 10 in a list does not return correct answers

Tags: python, list, indexing

I wanted to write an algorithm to see what number is more than 10 in an array and print it out, but rather than showing 27 it shows 4.

What did I do wrong?

My code is looking like this:

```
def findLargestNumberinArray(arr):
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        if (arr[i] > 10):
            return i
    return -1
    
arr = [1, 9, 3, 27, 0.5, 4, 16, 2]
result = findLargestNumberinArray(arr)
if result != -1:
    print("Number is : " + str(result + 1))
else:
    print("No Number!")
```

And this is the output:

```
Number is : 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You return the index `i` instead of returning the value in the list, `arr[i]`.

Try this:

```
def findLargestNumberinArray(arr):
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        if (arr[i] > 10):
            return arr[i]
    return -1
    
arr = [1, 9, 3, 27, 0.5, 4, 16, 2]
result = findLargestNumberinArray(arr)
if result != -1:
    print("Number is : " + str(result))
else:
    print("No Number!")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it more and more better than using for loops!
Look at this code:

```py
import numpy as np

arr = [1, 9, 3, 27, 0.5, 4, 16, 2]
Arr = np.array(arr)

New_Arr = Arr[Arr>10]
```

Then if you try to print `New_Arr`:

```py
print(New_Arr)
```

> array([27., 16.])

---

and if you want it more dynamic:

```py
import numpy as np
def More_Than_n(arr , n):
    """
    [Parameters]:

        + arr:(list)
            a list that you want find its components that are more than n
        
        + n:(int)
            an integer
    """

    Arr = np.array(arr)
    return Arr[Arr>n]
```

then caling the function:

```py
result = More_Than_n([1, 9, 3, 27, 0.5, 4, 16, 2] , 10)
print(result)
```

> array([27., 16.])

Comment: Nice one too. I am using an online compiler thats what

Comment: @Max you mean interpreters like google colab or kaggle?

Comment: this one https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/online-compiler/

Comment: @Max I tried my script there and every thing was okay! You can try this code in that online interpreter yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are making two mistakes:

1. First you are running the loop from `i` to `range(len(arr))` which will not count the last element
2. Secondly you are returning index instead of the element.

```
def findLargestNumberinArray(arr):

     for i in range(len(arr)+1):
        print(i)
        if (arr[i] > 10):
            return arr[i]
     return -1
    
    arr = [1,9,3,27,0.5,4,16,40]
    result = findLargestNumberinArray(arr)
    if result !=-1:
       print("Number is : " +str(result)
    else:
       print("No Number!")
```